# While running chef client command i am getting a warning - No config file found

Tags: chef-infra, chef-client

While running chef client command `chef-client -zr "recipe[test-cookbook::test-recipe]"` I am getting the below warning.

```
[2023-08-27T10:00:19+00:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line. Using command line options instead.
Chef Infra Client, version 18.2.7
Patents: https://www.chef.io/patents
Infra Phase starting
Resolving cookbooks for run list: ["test-cookbook::test-recipe"]
Synchronizing cookbooks:
  - test-cookbook (0.1.0)
Installing cookbook gem dependencies:
Compiling cookbooks...
Loading Chef InSpec profile files:
Loading Chef InSpec input files:
Loading Chef InSpec waiver files:
Converging 0 resources

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Infra Phase complete, 0/0 resources updated in 02 seconds
```

PS: I have updated the code correctly in recipe

The recipe is as below (syntax is OK as well):

```rb
file '/myfile' do
  content 'Welcome to Technical Guftgu'
  action :create
end
```

Comment: As the warning indicates, there is no config file for chef-client. Also you are using `-z`, (local mode). This means that you need to store you cookbooks, environment, roles in specific directory structure. For your use-case [this](https://www.chef.io/blog/chef-client-z-from-zero-to-chef-in-8-5-seconds) should give an idea.